# Using FFMPEG concat to produce a short output video

Tags: image, ffmpeg, concatenation

I need to concatenate 306 images using FFMPEG.
so, I proceed with the following script shell :

```
touch input.txt

for i in `seq 0 305`;
do
  echo "file $i.png" >> input.txt
  echo "duration 1" >> input.txt
done

echo "file 305.png" >> input.txt

ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -vf fps=10 -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mp4
```

1. I can't find the right parameters for concat.
2. I searching about duration, I can't find if it's possible to specify
   less than 1 second.
3. Every time, I change fps, the duration of output video became so
   big; example: if fps = 10 , output video duration = 3060 seconds

also, I tried :

```
 1. ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -vf fps=10 -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p
    video.mp4
 2. ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -y -vf fps=1 -crf 22 -threads 2
    -preset veryfast video.mp4
```

I tried also, with duration 1 for all images, the final video show only 1 image.

I need to concat those images and produce a short output video.

any idea

Comment: Go with `ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -r 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mp4`

Comment: thks so much :) , it work, the duration of output video is  00:05:06.70
any option to reduce ?

Comment: Reduce duration value in script.

Comment: @Gyan , it's already 1 for every image

Comment: That stands for seconds. You need to reduce that for shorter duration, like `0.5` for half a second.

Comment: it work @Gyan ; thks a lot